# How to send x-www-form-urlencoded request by react?

Tags: reactjs

```
static sendHelp() {
        const data = {
            data: {"AuthAD": "true"}
        };
        console.log(data);
        const config = {
            headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        };
        return axios.post('http://kashkin:20880', data, {config}).then(
            response => response.data
        );
    }
```

When i use this i have answer 401 unauthorized and dont know how to send data correctly?

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://kashkin:20880/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "AuthAD": "true"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

This is code from insomnia and it is work correct! How to use it in react( my format code?)
[image: when i use this.state.data it doesnt help to me]

[image: with ur method]

Comment: You have nested the data like `data.data`, is that intended? The jquery code does not nest it.

Comment: it doesnt mind if i use data or this.state.data with this needed json

Comment: You misunderstood the comment. Your React code has (essentially) `{ data: { data: {"AuthAD": "true"}}}` but the jQuery code has `{ data: {"AuthAD": "true"}}`. They are not the same thing.

Comment: on pic 2 static sendHelp(test) {
  const data = {
   data: {"AuthAD": "true"}
  };
  console.log(test);
  const config = {
   headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  };
  return axios.post(`http://kashkinbaevt:20880`, data.data, config).then(
   response => response.data
  );
 }

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) docs:

> ### [Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)
>
> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to `JSON`. To send data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format instead, you can use one of the following options.
>
> **Browser**
>
> In a browser, you can use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API as follows:
>
> ```js
> const params = new URLSearchParams();
> params.append('param1', 'value1');
> params.append('param2', 'value2');
> axios.post('/foo', params);
> ```
>
> Note that `URLSearchParams` is not supported by all browsers (see [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams)), but there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) available (make sure to polyfill the global environment).
>
> Alternatively, you can encode data using the [`qs`](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) library:
>
> ```
> const qs = require('qs');
> axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 }));
> ```
>
> Or in another way (ES6),
>
> ```js
> import qs from 'qs';
> const data = { 'bar': 123 };
> const options = {
>   method: 'POST',
>   headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
>   data: qs.stringify(data),
>   url,
> };
> axios(options);
> ```
>
> **Node.js**
>
> In node.js, you can use the [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module as follows:
>
> ```js
> const querystring = require('querystring');
> axios.post('http://something.com/', querystring.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));
> ```
>
> You can also use the [`qs`](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) library.

So, in your case, do it like this:

```js
// import the `qs` module
import qs from 'qs';

// Then you can use `qs` with `axios` in that file
const data = {
  "AuthAD": "true"
};
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url: 'http://kashkin:20880'
};
axios(options)
```

*Note: Remember, you'll have to install the `qs` package first (by running `npm install --save qs` command or the equivalent command for your preferred package manager.)*

Comment: So, there is no way beside this way? Axios + qs? Can’t do with fetch only?

Answer (score 0):

`{config}` by doing this, you are setting the config to an object in the form,

```js
{config} = { config: { headers: '...' }
```

Pass the `config` directly, the same goes for the `data` object.

```
const data = {"AuthAD": "true"};
return axios.post('http://kashkin:20880', data, config)
            .then(response => response.data);
```

Comment: without this i have 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: without what? this is the correct way to set headers, your data object is wrong as well, let me edit that in.

Comment: on picture number 2 
static sendHelp(test) {
  const data = {
   data: {"AuthAD": "true"}
  };
  console.log(test);
  const config = {
   headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  };
  return axios.post(`http://kashkinbaevt:20880`, data.data, config).then(
   response => response.data
  );
 }

Comment: Refer to the other answer, apparently there are complications surrounding url encoded data.